# AJAX keep loading - how can I bind this or prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bind

I'm struggling with this for weeks now and I've tried numerous ways.

This is an ajax search function. If I initiate a search, it just keeps loading several times. The more I search, the more times it loads.

This is my search function:

```
$("#q").on('submit', function (e) {


        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

        $("#q").off('submit');

        console.log('#################');
        console.log('search Initiated');
        console.log('#################');

        var frm = $('#q');
        var url = frm.attr('action');

        if (reloaddiv === undefined) {
            var reloaddiv = "reload";
        }
        if (reloadurl === undefined) {
            var reloadurl = frm.attr('action');
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('Search: Preparing');
                prepareBeforeAjax(reloaddiv, reloadurl);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.records').html(data);
                console.log('Search: Success');
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log('Search: Complete');
                hideModalIfVisible();
            },
            always: function () {
                $("#q").on('submit', e);
            }
        })

    });
```

And this is my console log

```
#################
subscriptions:1037 search Initiated
subscriptions:1038 #################
subscriptions:1055 Search: Preparing
subscriptions:941 prepareBeforeAjax
subscriptions:1036 #################
subscriptions:1037 search Initiated
subscriptions:1038 #################
subscriptions:1055 Search: Preparing
subscriptions:941 prepareBeforeAjax
subscriptions:1036 #################
subscriptions:1037 search Initiated
subscriptions:1038 #################
subscriptions:1055 Search: Preparing
subscriptions:941 prepareBeforeAjax
subscriptions:1036 #################
subscriptions:1037 search Initiated
subscriptions:1038 #################
subscriptions:1055 Search: Preparing
subscriptions:941 prepareBeforeAjax
subscriptions:1060 Search: Success
subscriptions:975 ------------
subscriptions:976 initReady Initiated
subscriptions:977 ------------
subscriptions:1063 Search: Complete
subscriptions:1060 Search: Success
subscriptions:975 ------------
subscriptions:976 initReady Initiated
subscriptions:977 ------------
subscriptions:1063 Search: Complete
subscriptions:1060 Search: Success
subscriptions:975 ------------
subscriptions:976 initReady Initiated
subscriptions:977 ------------
subscriptions:1063 Search: Complete
subscriptions:1060 Search: Success
subscriptions:975 ------------
subscriptions:976 initReady Initiated
subscriptions:977 ------------
subscriptions:1063 Search: Complete
```

`initReady` - This is basically just another JavaScript function I call after each ajax post - I do this because when making use of modals, I don't have to load all.

Answer (score -1):

The function looks like it keeps calling itself because of:

```
always: function () {
    $("#q").on('submit', e);
}
```

Comment: i mean, to me that looks more like an event binding, but even if it were, it is invalid because `e` isn't a function. it certainly isn't *triggering* the event again.